# Adding a delay to droppable event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a droppable element with a dropover event handler. Dragging an element over the droppable expands a node. However, I want to add a delay so the node does not expand immediately, i.e. you have to hold the draggable over the droppable for a second before it expands.

```
droppable.over = function(event, ui) {
    // expand node if dragover lasts 1000 milliseconds
    node.expand();
};
```

My first thought was to simply use `setTimeout` on `node.expand()`, but this doesn't do what I want, it simply delays the node expanding. It doesn't look like there's any configuration I can set to achieve this, so I'm wondering how I can do it.

Comment: You might consider having a global variable that you set = to the timeout and have another function for when the mouse goes out to cancel the setTimeout job.

Comment: No sure if you might be able to adapt the following so it detects if user is hovering while dragging an element. http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
var globalTimer;

//..
droppable.over = function(event, ui)
{
    globalTimer = setTimeout(function(){node.expand()}, 1000);
},
droppable.out = function(event, ui)
{
    clearTimeout(globalTimer);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this `setTimeout(function () { node.expand() }, 1000);`

but I might misunderstood you, do you want the node to appear later or appear only if it stays in the droppable for 1000 ms?

Comment: I tried this already as I described in my question, but this isn't the behavior I'm looking for. I only want the node to to expand if it's in the droppable for 1000 milliseconds.