# jQuery droppable - Fire special event after 2 seconds of holding div "over" droppable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to create a function that only executes when a draggable is held over a droppable area for at least 2 seconds. Meaning that if the draggable is dropped or removed within 2 seconds, the function doesn't execute.

My own logic is taking me in the following direction, does this seem correct?

```
over: function (){
    // Execute a timeout function after 2 seconds
},
out: function(){
    // Cancel the function
},
drop: function(){
    // Cancel the function
}
```

If so... How do I cancel an already initiated function? If not, is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to get 2 states.
 1. draggable event state
 2. droppable:hover event state.

the droppable:hover has a timeout of 2 secs
you want to be sure that the event is only fired if the 2 events exist.

You will be hovering when you drop, so you want to cancel the function if droppable event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the exact same solution as you and found it here:
[Adding a delay to droppable event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786598/adding-a-delay-to-droppable-event)

AceCorbans solution is formatted a bit differently, and I am used to seeing it in the style of your example. However, just think of `droppable.over = function{event, ui}` as the equivalent of `drop: function(){}` and it should work for you as well!